# Rails greater_than model validation against model attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I've got a Trip model, which among other attributes has a start_odometer and end_odometer value. 
In my model, i'd like to validate that the end odometer is larger than the starting odometer.
The end odometer can also be blank because the trip may not have finished yet.

However, I can't figure out how to compare one attribute to another.

In trip.rb:

comparing against the symbol:

```
validates_numericality_of :end_odometer, :greater_than => :start_odometer, :allow_blank => true
```

gives me the error:

> ArgumentError in TripsController#index
>
> :greater_than must be a number

comparing against the variable:

```
validates_numericality_of :end_odometer, :greater_than => start_odometer, :allow_blank => true
```

> NameError in TripsController#index
>
> undefined local variable or method `start_odometer' for #

Comment: I feel this would be something useful in Rails. Perhaps submit a ticket to the Lighthouse: http://rails.lighthouseapp.com for it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You'll probably need to write a custom validation method in your model for this...

```
validate :odometer_value_order

def odometer_value_order
  if self.end_odometer && (self.start_odometer > self.end_odometer)
    self.errors.add_to_base("End odometer value must be greater than start odometer value.")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 35):

You don't necessarily need a custom validation method for this case.  In fact, it's a bit overkill when you can do it with one line.  jn80842's suggestion is close, but you must wrap it in a Proc or Lambda for it to work.

```
validates_numericality_of :end_odometer, :greater_than => Proc.new { |r| r.start_odometer }, :allow_blank => true
```

Comment: Was looking for the same thing and this approach works great for me.

Comment: No need for a `Proc` either, just `:start_odometer` will work.

Answer (score 9):

You can validate against a model attribute if you use a Proc.

In rails4 you would do something like this:

```
class Trip < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_numericality_of :start_odometer, less_than: ->(trip) { trip.end_odometer }
  validates_numericality_of :end_odometer, greater_than: ->(trip) { trip.start_odometer }
end
```

Answer (score -4):

It's a bit kludgy, but this seems to work:

```
validates_numericality_of :end_odometer, :greater_than => :start_odometer.to_i, :allow_blank => true
```

Comment: Most definitely does not work, this converting the symbol `:start_odometer` to an integer and passes that to `:greater_than`. **Do not use this code, it is completely wrong**.