# Rails: validates_length_of

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to validate the Discount of a Sale in my Sale model.

The form for creating a Sale receives the Product data from my Warehouse model and saves it inside the Sale record:

```
<%= f.select(:product, Warehouse.pluck(:product).uniq, {prompt:true}, {class: 'form-control'}) %>
```

The Warehouse model has the discount specified for this respective product. Now I want to check if the `sale.product` is equal to the `warehouse.product` and then set the discount limit for this sale. Is that possible? Something like this:

```
validates_length_of :discount, maximum: Warehouse.where(:product => @sales.product).pluck(:discount), message: "Discount is to high"
```

Many Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you look at the Rails documentation ? It seems to have exactly what you need: `validates :name, length: { maximum: 2 }` http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#length

Comment: Yes. But I don't want to give a fix number, as the number depends on the specific product that is going to be sold.

Comment: You need this at runtime, not sure, but I think you can pass a lambda to `maximum`.

Comment: Wait. Do you want to limit **length of a string** or **a numeric value**?

Comment: @D-side numeric value (float)

Comment: Then you don't want to validate `length`, but rather `numericality`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you should be validating `numericality` for numeric values.

Custom validation is **unnecessary**. You don't have to use constants or literals or other class-evaluation time values! Use **procs**! [They will be called!](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations/numericality.rb#L52)

You pass a key as a comparison and then a **proc** as a value, so it is called during validation.

```
valudates_numericality_of :discount,
  less_than_or_equal_to: proc { |model| Something.query(whatever).pluck(:wow) },
  message: "is too high"
```

**Note:** you should probably also add a check for whether it's positive.

---

**Bonus** (pure fun, best not use): almost the same code with a spectacular amount of arrows
(in order: symbol `<=`, hashrocket `=>`, stabby-lambda `-> () {}`):

```
valudates_numericality_of :discount,
  :<= => -> (model) { Something.query(whatever).pluck(:wow) },
  :message => "is too high"
```

Note that 1.9 hash syntax won't work with a symbol like `<=` (like `<=: value`) so you have to stick to a hashrocket with this one, which is... another bit of pure fun.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a custom validation

in your model

```
validate :maximum_discout

  def maximum_discount
    if Warehouse.where(:product => @sales.product).pluck(:discount).all?{|d| d > self.discount }
      errors.add(:discount, "It should not cross the maximum discount")
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

For this task you should use a custom validation. Please see: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods

Answer (score 0):

To add to `D-side`'s answer (and to use [this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7138014/1143732)), you'll want to also work with the relevant data (not calling a new db query):

```
#app/models/sale.rb
class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :product, class_name: "Warehouse", foreign_key: "product", inverse_of: :sales
    validates :discount, numericality: { less_than_or_equal_to: Proc.new{|sale| sale.product.discount } } 

end

#app/models/warehouse.rb
class Warehouse < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :sales, inverse_of: :product
end
```